# bash_profile stops after file call

Tags: bash

I have the following code in my .bash_profile that automates a couple of file write tasks I need to run.

```
# Compile cron jobs for server
do_cron()
{
cd ~/Sites/MAMP/mywebsite/.ebextensions && sed 's/WEBSITE_URL/mywebsite.com/g' ./cron_jobs_sample.txt > ./cron_jobs.txt
}

# Compile config file so that we push to the right server
do_config()
{
cd ~/Sites/MAMP/mywebsite/.elasticbeanstalk/ && echo "[global]
ApplicationName=xxxx
DevToolsEndpoint=xxxx
EnvironmentName=xxxx
Region=xxxx" > ./config
}

# Do compiling
alias websitecompile=do_cron && do_config
```

I simply call:

```
$ websitecompile
```

And it runs my tasks.

The issue is it runs `do_cron` just fine, but `do_config` does not run. If I switch my code to run `do_config` first, both run fine.

```
alias websitecompile=do_config && do_cron
```

So something in `do_cron` seems to kill the process. I want to keep expanding on these commands so is there any way to stop it from stopping.

I am running Max OS X Mavericks.

Any ideas on what I can do to make this work as expected?

Comment: Using && between commands means the next command will only run if the first has no errors (exits with code 0).  Have you gone through each command to verify they work?  Run each command one at a time and do `echo $?` immediately after running it so verify the exit code is 0.  Also, this is probably better suited for superuser as there's nothing specific to server administration here.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Whoops, I'm still very new with the command line so apologies if I'm on the wrong site. Yes I have verified they all work. I just ran `cd ~/Sites/MAMP/mywebsite/.ebextensions && sed 's/WEBSITE_URL/mywebsite.com/g' ./cron_jobs_sample.txt > ./cron_jobs.txt && echo $?` and it returned `0`. Anything else I could try?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are there missing quotes in the script excerpt? Because the command:

```
alias websitecompile=do_cron && do_config
```

will alias `websitecompile` to `do_cron`, and immediately execute `do_config` (*not* include it in the alias). What you want is:

```
alias websitecompile='do_cron && do_config'
```

...which will include both commands in the alias.

Comment: Nice catch.  I missed that entirely.

Comment: That was it! Thanks so much! I'm a bit of a n00b but learning fast!

Answer (score 2):

From the Bash documentation for [aliases](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html):

> For almost every purpose, shell functions are preferred over aliases.

```
websitecompile () { do_cron && do_config; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check exit status for each command executed inside do_cron() and return a right function status if they are well executed. I think some command is exiting with a n unexpected status that makes fail the do_cron && do_config condition.